# Future_to_publish into postmeta

Tags: posts

Based on an example [found on this page](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/confirm-that-publish_future_post-hook-does-not-work/), I attempted to use this in my plugin. Nothing fired. A note [on this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) stated publish_future_post is deprecated and replaced with future_to_publish. This also failed.

Therefore, I tried to make a simple plugin with only this add_action into the plugin. Once again, the postmeta was not updated.

Here is the code in the "future post" plugin.

```
function future_publish ( $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hook_fired', 'true' );
}

add_action( 'future_to_publish', 'future_publish' );
```

I've been going round and round. Some people are posting the transition status works fine, others say it cannot be wrapped in is_admin, and still, I cannot get a scheduled post to actually fire anything except for the post to WP. I cannot hook into it.

Has anyone actually tried to hook in and had something happen after the scheduled post becomes published?

Update: Please excuse my typing. I meant published and originally typed post. It's due to my frustration with this topic.

Update Number 2: I copied the code from an answer which is specific to $old == 'future' and this worked to update the meta. Great. But the code after the meta (not shown here) doesn't run. At least now I know that the action is working when $old == 'future'. I'm not sure why the rest of the code after doesn't work but that would be a different question.

For now, I can only assume that the code $old != 'publish' does not fire scheduled posts and the 'future' must be specified. I'll mark the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `publish_future_post` action hook. Contrary to what Codex says, it is not deprecated, and it works with WordPress 4.8.2. Your code should be:

```
function my_test_future_post( $post_id ) {
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'hook_fired', 'true' );
}
add_action( 'publish_future_post', 'my_test_future_post' );
```

Tested!

### Update

If you are concerned about `publish_future_post` hook being deprecated, use `transition_post_status` hook:

```
function my_test_future_post( $new, $old, $post ) {
    if ( $post->post_type == 'post' && $new == 'publish' && $old == 'future' )
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'hook_fired', 'You bet!' );
}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_test_future_post', 10, 3 );
```

Tested in `functions.php` and plugins.

Comment: While it might still work at the moment it's a big risk to use it - if the Codex says its deprecated, then it could be removed at any time and break the functionality. It would be preferable to get it working from the start with functions that are confirmed to be part of the core, to be sure :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten I've updated my answer, to address your concerns.

Comment: Interesting because that isn’t working on my test environment.

Comment: The key was using a different conditional in which $old == 'future' rather than using $old != 'publish'

Answer (score 2):

**Update**:

Now that you've changed your question (and made my original answer look completely wrong!):

I haven't used the hook future_to_publish, but I *have* successfully used the `transition_post_status` action (also referenced in the [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)) to detect status changes.

Something similar to this has worked for me before:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_status_change', 10, 3 );

function my_status_change( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ($old_status=="future" && $new_status=="publish"){
        // do stuff....
    }
}
```

---

I think you might have mixed up 2 hooks? The [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) refers to the following hooks:

1. **{old_status}_to _{new_status} Hook**

> An {old_status}*to*{new_status} action will execute when a post transitions from {old_status} to {new_status}.

In your case: future_to_*publish* (future_to_*post* won't work because *post* isn't a status

2. **{status}_{post_type} Hook**

> A {status}_{post_type} action will execute when a post of type {post_type} transitions to {status} from any other status.

In your case: This would be publish_post (I think this may be where you got them mixed up?)

I assume you only want future to publish transitions so try:

```
add_action( 'future_to_publish', 'future_publish' );
```

Comment: No hook I've tried has worked. In the example in this question, I'm showing code which postings in other locations shows should add to postmeta. However, this fails. Have you tried to get something to fire after a scheduled post?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice my typing and indeed meant future_to_publish. Regardless, my question is one of exasperation. Has anyone successfully hooked into scheduled posts?

Comment: @LPH yes, my updated answer has tested code.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz So does mine :)

Comment: @LPH So does mine :) As I say in my updated answer, `transition_post_status` has always worked for me.

Comment: I'm glad, everyone is happy :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten just noticed. Check `if` statement in your code, it always returns false. I'm sure it is just a typo.

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz woops! Thanks for letting me know. Yes, one should be old_status of course. Thats what I get for typing off the top of my head :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66460/discussion-between-frank-p-walentynowicz-and-fluffykitten).

Comment: I’m using an iPad at the moment and about to hop on the Development machine. This code hasn’t worked for years so something must be blocking it. I’m going to build a new test site and see what happens.

Comment: @LPH I am currently using it on a site with running WP4.8 and its working away perfectly. I'm using it in exactly the same was as in my answer, and that code is called in the callback function for `add_action( 'init'...)`. There's also a plugin "Edit Flow" that uses it successfully, if it helps to check out the code in it. (If you do check that plugin, its used in modules/notification/notifications.php).

Comment: Something is blocking the code from working. The scheduled post will publish but meta isn't updated. It's rather frustrating. Yes. I've looked at Edit Flow. It's a nice plugin but that doesn't help me figure out why future transition doesn't work nor the publish_future_post in my code. I'm trying to build another test site.

Comment: @LPH I just thought it might help to compare a working example as I assumed your `transition_post_status` wasn't getting triggered at all. But from what you describe, it sounds like it is but its just not saving? In that case it could be the order in which they are executed based on the priority. I'd issues with this for save_{}_post before.

Comment: After changing to 'future' then the update meta worked and now I'm trying to get code to run after a post is published -- which is a copy of the post written to a forum.